# How can I plot an equation into an array with redefined indices

Tags: python

So I have an equation lets say: `x^2 + y^2`

Currently, I can make an array that defines the equation, calculates the array based off input parameters and and prints out an array:

```
def equation(x,y):
  return x**2 + y**2

def calculate(x, y, xmin, ymin):
  out = []
  for i in range(x_min, xs):
    row = []
    for j in range(y_min, ys):
      row.append(equation(i, j))
    out.append(row)
  return out
```

The output array calculates the values based off the indicies 
output such that `(0,0)` is upper left. Given an array with length and width, how can I calculate the equation so that the `(0,0)` is centered and follows a cartesian plane?

Comment: The output of  `calculate(-5, -5, 5, 5)`, for example, will have `(0, 0)` in the center.

Comment: Just to check, do you intend to define a 3d curve, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To center your data around 0,0,0 and plot the result, you could do something like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def equation(x,y):
  return x**2 + y**2

x = [(i-50)/10 for i in range(0,100,1)]
y = x
z = [equation(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)]

# plot the function
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
# rotate the plot so we can see the 3 dimensions
for angle in range(0, 360):
  ax.view_init(30, angle)
  plt.draw()
  plt.pause(.001)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would just need to redefine what you are iterating over to put `(0, 0)` in the middle. I would suggest that you use a library like [numpy](https://www.numpy.org/) though and take advantage of vectorized functions to speed up (and simplify) your code. For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)  # create 11 points arranged from -1 to 1
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)  # this produces the input values you'd get out of your double loop
result = np.square(X) + np.square(Y)  # your equation, applied to everything at once
```

I made an odd number of points centered at 0 so that we would actually have an input value of `(0, 0)` right in the center. We can plot the result with the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(result)
```

[image]

Note that the axis ticks are wrong here because `imshow` doesn't care what our original inputs were, but that dark spot in the center is your `(0, 0)` input point.